# Firebase Functions + CORS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Having an issue with a firebase function that I need to work with cors. Based off the documentation and all the posts I've read it should be working but seem's like no matter what I try I keep getting the same error:

```
Failed to load <URL>: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

And here is the corresponding code in my firebase functions index.js file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const stripe = require('stripe')('<TEST_KEY>');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({keyFilename: '<PATH_TO_KEY>'});
const Easypost = require('@easypost/api');
const api = new Easypost('<TEST_KEY>');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.processOrder = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {

    var body = JSON.parse(req.body);

    if (
      !body.shipment_id       ||
      !body.items             ||
      !body.card
    ) return res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*').send({error: true, message: 'Missing information'});


    getPrices(body.items, (err, prices, totalPrice) => {
      if (err) return res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*').send({error: err, message: "Error"})

      // Create a new customer and then a new charge for that customer:
      stripe.customers.create({
        email: 'test@example.com'
      }).then((customer) => {
        return stripe.customers.createSource(customer.id, {
          source: body.card.token.id
        });
      }).then((source) => {
        return stripe.charges.create({
          amount: (totalPrice * 100),
          currency: 'usd',
          customer: source.customer
        });
      }).then((charge) => {
        return res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*').send({error: false, message: "Success"});
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*').send({error: err, message: "Error"});
      });

    });
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**Edit:** Just wanted to note: I've tried only setting `res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` and not using the cors middleware, and I've tried not setting the header and only using cors. Neither of which worked :(

**Solution:** As @sideshowbarker said in a comment, my function had an error elsewhere before returning. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin was never even getting set. Once I fixed the error it was all good! Ty!

Comment: *The response had HTTP status code 500* indicates there’s some internal server failure happening — maybe before your code that sets the headers is ever run. Regardless, the server doesn’t add application-set headers to 500 error responses. It likely only adds them to 2xx success responses. So the problem is that you’re getting a 500 error instead of 200 success response. The mention of Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the client-side error message doesn’t indicate you have CORS support misconfigured on the server — instead it just indicates some other server failure happened.

Comment: are you using node.js?

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a look at my code to see if anything could be causing the 500 error that @sideshowbarker mentioned.

Comment: And yes it is using node.js @WillemvanderVeen

Answer (score 0):

In node you can use a package to solve this problem. To enable all CORS install the following package:

`npm install cors`

Then assuming you are using `express` you can then enable CORS by the following lines of code:

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```